# Is there a way to split one item in a stream into multiple items?

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

Consider the following stream:

```
--'[a,b,c]'--
```

The `'[a,b,c]'` is one item in the stream. Now I'm looking for a way to map that stream into this:

```
--'a'--'b'--'c'--
```

I think at some point I need to use `map` since I only know how to split the array:

```
Observable.from(['[a,b,c]'])
    .map(i => {
        let arr = JSON.parse(i);
        //Somehow inject the arr items into the stream (instead of arr itself)
    })
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

I wish to see three separate entries in the console with `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) instead of `map`:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .from(['["a", "b", "c"]'])
  .mergeMap(value => JSON.parse(value))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

`mergeMap` will flatten an array returned by the project function.